# Cars and Crash prediction

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have a specific problem, and I do not know how to solve it.

Problem:[image: Car and Crash Probability]

The table shows car examples, each with its characteristics. Each car type and respective specifications correspond to a crash rate, except for the example "F".

For simplicity, each car is made out of 7 components. Each of these components has a type variation and is manufactured by different companies. A company can produce one or more components.

Need answers for examples "E" and "F"
I need to find the currently produced components (x1, x4, x5, x6) that are found in car examples from "A" to "D" to produce a new car "E" with a crash probability of 0.6.
As for "F", I need to find the crash probability.

Thanks

Comment: How do you model crash probabilities as a function of components?  I doubt that an additive one (*aka* linear regression) would make any physical sense.

Comment: As you mentioned using linear could be not the best fit

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, the easiest way is to use regression. Take each feature as a dimension (including the model). Then fit. However, I think this is a purely mathematical computational problem that you can try to compute manually.

Comment: do you know what regression model I need to use for this ?

Comment: I think linear reg is enough.